# Flex Events run locally but not on server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I've got a very strange problem where the flex events work fine locally, but when the swf (same one) is published to the server, they're not working at all. The events seem to be getting fired, but not heard.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: have you tried it run locally but not in the folder which is compiled to?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have and it's still the same thing.

Comment: You mean it worked fine in other folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local file was compiling a swc as well as a swf. I ticked the 'include source' option in the Flex Compiler settings and it worked. Thanks.